# How to show NSMutableArray in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

I am making a game in Xcode and I need to get the score shown on the screen. I am showing the score as images instead of using a normal font. This is my code so far:

```
NSString *score = @"132";

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:score.length];

for (int i = 0; i < score.length; i++) {
    // imageName will be @"1", then @"3" and @"2"
    NSString *imageName = [[score substringToIndex:i] substringToIndex:1];

    // add extension
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    [images addObject:image];
}
```

How would I get the `NSMutableArray` to show in a `UIImageView` so it shows on the main storyboard at the top. I have tried things like:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imagescore.size.width, imagescore.size.height)];
imageView.image = images;
```

Comment: I don't know of any way to show an NSMutableArray in any sort of view.  You might be able to show some of the *contents* of the array in an image view, but no one would care whether those contents came from an array or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show three (or however many) images, you will need the same number of imageViews. Create an imageView for each image (make sure they don't have the same frame, I imagine you'll want them laid out next to each other).